# Safely killing the child thread (infinte loop) before leaving the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, parent-child

I have a main function which has generated two threads for updation of JDBC SQL results. The child threads exclusively work are in infinite loop and update the results after five minutes. I want before exiting the main thread, child tread should be killed.

What is the best procedure for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume your code is like this:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What you can do is implement a flag:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean shouldStop = false;

    public void run() {
        while(!shouldStop) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public void stopTask() {
        shouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

then in the main thread:

```
ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask(); 
Thread t = new Thread(task);
t.start();
...
task.stopTask();
t.join();
```

Comment: Do I have to use locks for the variable shouldStop

Comment: No problem, I searched ofr volatile keyword . it is taking care of that. Thanks